# One sender disconnecting causes all senders to disconnect

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I am experimenting with a modified version of the Cast-HelloText sample app, specifically having two senders connect to the app at the same time.

The castReceiverManager.onSenderConnected() callback is called, and I see I have 2 senders connected (using window.castReceiverManager.getSenders().length) and both can then send messages.

However, when either one disconnects the app is terminated. I have tried logging the number of senders connected in the castReceiverManager.onSenderDisconnected() callback (without success) and I have commented out the window.close() call.

It appears the app is closed (chromecast returns to home screen) on any sender disconnecting.

Any ideas on how to have an app with more than one sender that isn't ended when any sender disconnects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check on your sender to see what it does when a disconnect happens. The unmodified version on Github calls `Cast.CastApi.stopApplication(mApiClient)` when you disconnect your sender from the receiver and that call stops the app on the receiver. If you don't want that to happen, you should not call that method but then you need to make sure

- it makes sense for your app to continue
- make sure your receiver handles things correctly

Comment: Bingo! I hadn't spent any time studying the sender API or sample code yet (was slogging through the receiver API), and in fact you were spot on. The receiver stops itself when it no longer has any connected senders - so that takes care of that. Thanks.

Comment: BTW: in the sample code, that means the code "if (window.castReceiverManager.getSenders().length == 0) {window.close();}" (in receiver.html) is redundant, as the sender ends the app first - and so a little misleading.

Comment: That is not redundant; your sender may go outside of wifi range, or may go to sleep, so it can get disconnected without you know about it, hence receiver has that code. Again, it depends on the nature of your application whether it has to stop if there is no sender connected or it should keep going; if it is, say, Netflix, I would want that to keep going if all connected devices go to sleep and lose connectivity.

Comment: OK. I see that now. Thanks for pointing out that other case where the Sender can get Disconnected.